# Drop down value not inserting into database in loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

Here i am trying to insert the selected drop-down value to database. but here what happening is.

Here i have multiple textboxes and dropdown boxes next to it. the values from textbox is getting inserted to database properly. but the drop down values are not getting inserted into database properly..

for example:
Assume that there are 3 textboxes and drop down list. 
now i enter some data to textbox and select the value in drop down and click submit.

when i click submit.
the three text box values are inserted to database properly. but the drop down values are not inserted properly.
but it is inserting the last dropdown value 3 times...

how can solve this?

javascript and php code: this code generates the textboxes and drop downs dynamically

```
function create(param) {
    'use strict';
    var i, target = document.getElementById('screens');
    target.innerHTML = '';
    target.innerHTML = '<input name="RowCount" value="' + param + '" hidden />';
    for(i = 0; i < param; i += 1) {

       target.innerHTML +='</br>';
       target.innerHTML +='New Movie '+i+'  ';
       target.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="Fname_' + i + '">';

       target.innerHTML +='  '+'Language '+'  ';
       target.innerHTML += "<?php 
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=theaterdb;host=localhost','tiger','tiger');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

        $sql = 'SELECT language FROM languages;';

        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute();

        echo "<select name='language' id='course'>";
        echo "<option>----Select Language----</option>"; 
        while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['language'] ."'>" . $row['language']. "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
?>";

       target.innerHTML +='</br>';
       target.innerHTML +='</br>';
    }
}
```

php code to get the textbox and dropdown values

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "tiger", "tiger") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("theaterdb") or die(mysql_error());
for ($i=0; $i < $_POST["range"] ; $i++)
{
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO movie (movie_name,language) VALUES('" . $_POST['Fname_' . $i] . "','" . $_POST['language'] . "') ") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: You can't use PHP inside anything created with JS. PHP runs on the server BEFORE anything is passed to the client browser. Once there, it can't execute the PHP as PHP is run on the server, not inside the web browser.

Comment: Pls stop using the deprecated mysql. Use myslqi or pdo instead.

Comment: please split php logic, javascript code and html output :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide different `name` attributes for each `select`. The way you are doing for the `textfield`.

You can use the same trick that you are using for the text-fields. That is, append the name of the `selects` with the loop-index.